# How to Make the Music Loop After the Music Ends Android

Tags: android, media-player

I just wanted the music in my activity to play endlessly (i.e. when my 38-second music ends, i wanted to play it again and again until the user leaves the page). By the way, i am using MediaPlayer.

```
 ourSound = MediaPlayer.create(NewKFCActivity.this, R.raw.start);
 ourSound.start();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call [`MediaPlayer#setLooping(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29):

```
ourSound = MediaPlayer.create(NewKFCActivity.this, R.raw.start);
ourSound.setLooping(true);
ourSound.start();
```